# How to add only sumdigit column values having same _id in given array and price column should remain same in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

input array =>

```
[{_id: "555", sumdigit: 1000,  Price: 1000}{_id: "677", sumdigit: 10,  Price: 320} {_id: "555", sumdigit: 170, Price: 1000}  {_id: "444", sumdigit: 10,  Price: 1000} {_id: "400", sumdigit: 10,  Price: 320}]
```

output array =>

```
[{_id: "555", sumdigit: 1170,  Price: 1000},{_id: "677", sumdigit: 10,  Price: 320},{_id: "444", sumdigit: 10,  Price: 1000}, {_id: "400", sumdigit: 10,  Price: 320}]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: yes but i was trying though traditional JavaScript  method, but i want to use es6 methods

Comment: 1. Add your attempt, 2. What's the difference between "traditional JavaScript" and "ES6 JavaScript"?

Comment: Okay next time I'll do this way thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you want:

```js
const a = [{ _id: "555", sumdigit: 1000, Price: 1000 }, { _id: "677", sumdigit: 10, Price: 320 }, { _id: "555", sumdigit: 170, Price: 1000 }, { _id: "444", sumdigit: 10, Price: 1000 }, { _id: "400", sumdigit: 10, Price: 320 }];

console.log([...a.reduce((a, c) => {
    if (a.has(c._id)) {
        a.get(c._id).sumdigit += c.sumdigit;
    } else {
        a.set(c._id, c);
    }
    return a;
}, new Map()).values()])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use reduce to accumulate the values

```js
const arrays=[{_id: "555", sumdigit: 1000,  Price: 1000}, {_id: "677", sumdigit: 10,  Price: 320} , {_id: "555", sumdigit: 170, Price: 1000} , {_id: "444", sumdigit: 10,  Price: 1000} , {_id: "400", sumdigit: 10,  Price: 320}]

 res=arrays.reduce((acc,{_id,sumdigit,Price}) => {
   if(!acc[_id]) acc[_id] = {...acc[_id],_id,sumdigit,Price}
   else acc[_id] = {...acc[_id],_id:_id,
                   sumdigit : acc[_id].sumdigit + sumdigit,Price:Price}
   return acc
 },{})
 console.log(Object.values(res))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the output by iterate over the `input array` checking if the _id is in your output to increase the `sumdigit` property.

Try this code.

```js
const input = [
  {_id: "555", sumdigit: 1000,  Price: 1000},
  {_id: "677", sumdigit: 10,  Price: 320},
  {_id: "555", sumdigit: 170, Price: 1000},
  {_id: "444", sumdigit: 10,  Price: 1000},
  {_id: "400", sumdigit: 10,  Price: 320},
]


const output = [];

// Iterate over the input array
for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  const element = input[i];

  // Check if the id is already present in the output variable
  const prevObjectIdx = output.findIndex(obj => obj._id === element._id);

  /**
   * If the id is already into the output array just increase the subdigit with the other one.
   * Otherwise, just add the element into the output variable.
   */
  if (prevObjectIdx !== -1) {
    output[prevObjectIdx].sumdigit += element.sumdigit;
  } else {
    output.push(element);
  }
};


console.log(output)
```

Comment: i have tried this method, we have to write no. of lines in this code and which i don’t  want that’s  why i asked the question btw thanks for the help.